# JavaCC grammar - parse everything to the end of the file

Tags: grammar, gherkin, javacc, featurebnf

I am using [FeatureBNF](http://ckaestne.github.io/CIDE/gcidegrammar.html) (and so in essence I am using JavaCC) to try and write a grammar that will produce a (very) simple parser to parse [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin) files.

An example Gherkin file:

```
Feature: Calculator

   In order to avoid silly mistakes
   As a math idiot
   I want to be told the sum of two numbers

Scenario: Add two numbers
   Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
   And I have also entered 70 into the calculator
   When I press add
   Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

All I want to do, to begin with, is parse this into a `Feature` that has the name `Calculator` and a `Body`, which is the entirety of the rest of the file.

I have struggled with the part where I'm trying to read the rest of the file into the `Body` however.  I think maybe partially because there is no 'natural' delimiters for when one section ends - it's denoted by a newline.

Trying the following grammar:

```
<DEFAULT> TOKEN :
{
  <FEATURE: "Feature: " >
| <#LETTER: ["\u0027","\u0041"-"\u005a","\u005f","\u0061"-"\u007a"] >
| <FEATURE_NAME: (<LETTER>)+ >
| <NEWLINE: ("\r\n" | "\n\r" | "\r" | "\n") >
| <TEXT : ~[] >
}

GRAMMARSTART

Feature :
    <FEATURE> FeatureName <NEWLINE>
    Body
    <EOF>
    ;
FeatureName: <FEATURE_NAME>;
Body: (<TEXT>)*;
```

I get the error:

> [java] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> ... lots of stack trace removed...
>
> [java] Caused by: cide.gparser.ParseException: Encountered "\r\n" (5) at line 2, column 1.
>
> [java] Was expecting one of:
>
> [java]     <EOF>
>
> [java]     <TEXT> ...

I have been able to achieve what I want by adding some delimiters in to the Gherkin file and using lexical states, like so:

```
Feature: Calculator #TITLEEND
#BODYSTART
   In order to avoid silly mistakes
   As a math idiot
   I want to be told the sum of two numbers

Scenario: Add two numbers
   Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
   And I have also entered 70 into the calculator
   When I press add
   Then the result should be 120 on the screen
#BODYEND
```

With the following relevant parts of the grammar:

```
<DEFAULT, IN_BODY> SPECIAL_TOKEN : {
  " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" | "\f"
}

<DEFAULT> TOKEN : {
  <FEATURE: "Feature: " >
| <#LETTER: ["\u0027", "\u0041"-"\u005a", "\u005f", "\u0061"-"\u007a"] >
| <FEATURE_NAME: (<LETTER>)+ >
| <ENDFEATURETITLE: "#TITLEEND" >
}

<DEFAULT> TOKEN : { <BODYSTART : "#BODYSTART"> : IN_BODY }
<IN_BODY> TOKEN : { <TEXT : ~[] > }

<IN_BODY> TOKEN : { <BODYEND : "#BODYEND"> : DEFAULT } 

GRAMMARSTART

Feature:
    <FEATURE> FeatureName <ENDFEATURETITLE>
    Body
    <EOF>;
FeatureName: <FEATURE_NAME>;
Body: <BODYSTART> Text <BODYEND>;
Text: (<TEXT>)*;
```

But I am sure I must be missing something and would like to be able to achieve this without having to annotate the feature files.  What is a better way to do this?

---

#### SIDE NOTE

FeatureBNF builds on top of JavaCC and outputs a grammar file for JavaCC to process.  I am completely new to both FeatureBNF and JavaCC, but they seem similar enough that I hope this question might be applicable to JavaCC gurus.  (FeatureBNF uses JavaCC syntax for the lexical specifications and then its own format for the grammar's production rules.)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your grammar, you can switch states after the first newline, so the following lexical grammar will suffice:

```
<DEFAULT> TOKEN : {
   <FEATURE: "Feature: " >
   | <#LETTER: ["\u0027", "\u0041"-"\u005a", "\u005f", "\u0061"-"\u007a"] >
   | <FEATURE_NAME: (<LETTER>)+ >
   | <ENDFEATURETITLE: "#TITLEEND" >
   | <NEWLINE: ("\r\n" | "\n\r" | "\r" | "\n") > : IN_BODY
   }

<IN_BODY> TOKEN : { <TEXT : ~[] > }
```

Now the syntactic grammar is

```
Feature:
    <FEATURE> FeatureName <NEWLINE>
    Body
    <EOF>;
FeatureName: <FEATURE_NAME>;
Body: (<TEXT>)*;
```